# Paypal Express ActiveMerchant integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant, railscasts

I am following [Ryan Bates' railcast 146](http://railscasts.com/episodes/146-paypal-express-checkout) and it is really helpful.  However, Im trying to remove the cart object from the process, and just process an order individually.  The problem I am having is how to establish the amount which is used twice: once to setup the purchase, and then once to actually execute it.  This is what I have resorted to doing, but it exposes the amount in the return_url, which I think is probably bad practice:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def express
    response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(params[:amount],
      :ip                => request.remote_ip,
      :return_url        => new_order_url(:amount=>params[:amount]),
      :cancel_return_url => root_url
    )
    redirect_to EXPRESS_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token)
  end

  def new
    @order = Order.new(:express_token => params[:token], :price_in_cents=>params[:amount])
  end
```

Then in the view, I add a hidden field with the amount so that when the order is created it has the amount built in (I added a price_in_cents field to the order model).  It works fine, but exposing the amount as a param may be a little iffy. Finally, the purchase code looks like this:

```
 def purchase
    response = process_purchase
    transactions.create!(:action => "purchase", :amount => price_in_cents, :response => response)
    cart.update_attribute(:purchased_at, Time.now) if response.success?
    response.success?
  end
```

In short, how can I do this without passing around the amount in the params?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input guys. I ended up storing the amount in the user's session, something like `session[:amount]`, and then setting it to `nil` as soon as they finish the process.  That way its hidden from the user and saves me the trouble of creating new objects or encrypting.

Answer (score 0):

Sending the amount in the url is very bad practice - It allows one to change the price and purchase what ever you are selling for the amount he specifies in the URL.

I can see two ways around this issue:
1. You can encrypt the parameters you pass, and decrypt them from the URL. See how to encrypt [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/991)
2. You can create a new entity that holds the price of the purchase (or in case you are selling a specific item (since you are not using a cart) - you can pass the id of this item and query for it's price when you need it). Something like this:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def express
    @product = Product.find(params(:product_id));
    response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(product.price_in_cents,
      :ip                => request.remote_ip,
      :return_url        => new_order_url(product.price_in_cents),
      :cancel_return_url => root_url
    )
    redirect_to EXPRESS_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token)
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.find(params(:product_id));
    @order = Order.new(:express_token => params[:token], :price_in_cents=> @product.price_in_cents)
  end
```